# Are Roots in the JPA criteria API interchangeable between queries?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

In the JPA criteria API, are `Root`s interchangeable?

That is, if I am in the process of preparing two `CriteriaQuery` instances, and if I do this on one of them:

```
final Root<X> root = query.from(X.class);
```

...can I then use that `Root` instance when interacting with the second query?

I'd like to build up a `WHERE` clause programmatically in this manner and then use it in two queries.

Comment: If you have a method to construct the where clause, why don't you call it twice (once for each root)?

Comment: OK; I take it then that they are not interchangeable? Now I'm just curious; they therefore must have some sort of state they share with their parent criteria I guess.

Comment: Test it, but I indeed think they do. My point was that, if they are not interchangeable (or if you're in doubt and want to be safe), you can just call the method twice.

Comment: Thanks, and I do appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Root`s are not interchangeable, although the JPA specification does not explicitly call this out.